# Formulario con Select2 Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, select2

tengo un formulario que incluye un select2 que no tiene ningun problema pero se ve como mas aplastado, hay alguna forma de poder corregir esto?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código en el HTML

```
<div class="col-sm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="txtitulodeobra">Titulo de la obra</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtitulodeobra" placeholder="Ingrese el titulo de la obra"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="txttecnicaobra">Técnica de la obra</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txttecnicaobra" placeholder="Ingrese la técnica empleada"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="txtvalorobra">Valor de la obra</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtvalorobra" placeholder="Ingrese el valor de la obra">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm">
  <div class="form-group" data-select2-id="47">
    <label for="cmbartista">Artista de la obra</label>
    <select class="form-control js-example-basic-single" name="cmbartista">
      <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
      <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="txtartista">Valor de la obra</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtvalorobra" placeholder="Ingrese el valor de la obra">
  </div>
</div>
```

Y este es el javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya logre resolver mi pregunta con un css

```
.selection span{
  height: 38px !important;
}
```